# How to include a simple tax calculator in Broadleaf ecommerse

Tags: html, e-commerce, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

Im trying to create a poc with broadleaf ECommerce to develop a simple tax calculator .
I tried with whats explained on 
[broadleaf doc simple calculator](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/broadleaf-concepts/pricing/tax/simple-tax-provider") but when i login on admin pannel its showing "No values found for this enumeration".
Can anyone please help me how to setup this...

Comment: We need more information and sharing of your code. Specifically around the enumeration.

Answer (score 2):

The simple tax calculator included in the Broadleaf out of the box is not configurable in the admin. If you are talking about the 'Tax Code' field on Product and Category, that is configurable via data driven enumerations, but deciding what meaning the different tax codes have is a customization.

The data driven enumeration table is `BLC_DATA_DRVN_ENUM`. The admin will look up the values (in the `BLC_DATA_DRVN_ENUM_VAL` table) for the data driven enumeration who's key is TAX_CODE.

Again, the SimpleTaxProvider from the doc that you linked makes no use of this tax code and instead relies on Spring XML bean configuration.

Comment: You could add permissions to admin to manage 'Data Driven Enumeration' and add a new section to admin so you could manage enumerations from admin